# How can I create a dynamic rally dashboard?

Tags: project-management, rally, agile, dashboard, burndowncharts

I'm looking to make an Agile dashboard, or "information radiator," that shows information based on a combination of teams.

It will act as a display board in our hallways and in our project manager's areas.

The goal is to be able to dynamically move from customized view to customized view in a presentation mode.

I know with Rally I can view separate teams burn-downs, but is there a way I can look at 8 separate teams burn-downs on the same screen?  And the move to a different kind of information set after X seconds?

Each view should be a different "Screen" such as a PowerPoint looks when it moves from one view to another.  I'd like to set it on a timer

Example:

View 1:  Team 1's burn-down, Team 2's burn-down, etc...

View 2: Team 1's build results, Team 2's build results, etc...

View 3: Team 1's Bugs introduced, Team 2's bug introduced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can create a custom page called Team Burn Downs and then add burndown charts for each team- just edit the settings and choose a specific project scope rather than following the global.

Repeat for the builds and bugs pages.

There are browser extensions like [Revolver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revolver-tabs/dlknooajieciikpedpldejhhijacnbda?hl=en) which will automatically cycle through your open tabs.  We use this on our standup tv and it works great...

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to make sure I fit all the burndowns on the same page?  I can't fit a third row on my page, and if I make my view smaller it resizes the charts to show scrollbars without dynamically resizing the chart itself.

Comment: You should be able to drag the bottom of each chart to set its height- there are minimum heights though which you may be running up against...  You have your screen layout set to 3 column on the custom page though?